# Aggregation with AWS S3 serving gzip css and js

Tags: css, amazon-s3, drupal

We have the below set-up for our Drupal site

- /sites/default/files -> S3
- database -> RDS
- Site files -> EC2

The gzip file is getting generated in S3. I've tried going through S3 and applying the metadata settings for each gz file I can find, but I'm still being served uncompressed css.

Please can anyone help us in getting this resolved.

Thanks

Comment: I suspect you need to be **significantly** more specific with this question.  Capture request and response headers, perhaps, detailing what you observe and what yoi expect.  S3 serves exactly the object the browser requests, in exactly the format/encoding in which it was uploaded.